# How to set TestCase Step response from within a Groovy script in SoapUI

Tags: groovy, soapui

When a script is created in a TestCase in SoapUI, you get access to the following variables:

**log**, **context**, and **testRunner**

From **testRunner** I grab the TestCase Step of interest with:

```
def testStep = testRunner.getTestCase().getTestStepByName('TestCase Step 1')
```

After the test case is run with `testRunner.runTestStep(testStep)`, you get a response. I would like to modify that response, but when I try:

```
testStep.setPropertyValue('Response', "Sample response content: Lorem Ipsum")
```

I get: `Trying to set read-only property [Response]`

testStep is of type [RestTestRequestStep](https://www.soapui.org/apidocs/com/eviware/soapui/impl/wsdl/teststeps/RestTestRequestStep.html). I know that one can use MockRequests and set MockResponses, but for this one, I need data from an actual server with different queries, combine the data, and then give it as a response.

Is there a way to modify the response returned to a TestStep?

Comment: why don't you combine the data and set a custom property with it ? it will be accessible from your other steps

Comment: @g_l You want to modify the response in the same testStep or you want to get the response from that testStep and pass it to another testStep. 

PS: You can't modify the response in that testStep as the error rightly mentioned you are trying to modify the read-only property and the reason is you are fetching/reading some info via REST Call. If you need to modify the response I guess you have a REST POST/PUT method there and you can set your desired change in the body and you ll get the change in the Response.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the info, I can suggest that you can take the output in a property( Global Property, Project level property)  and pass/get the property in the following steps  to combine it.